# why peano defines 1 as natural?

Tags: arithmetic, peano-axioms

as long as i have researched i have found here in this presumed book from Peano

https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog/page/n6/mode/2up

that actually peano has defined the 1 as the first natural(page 1) since(acording to the book) 1 is  not the successor of another natural number; but in another places like wiki and wolfram

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

i have found the discrepancy that they define 0 as the first natural

my question here is not about the ground truth of the sentences "0 is element of Naturals" but rather i would like to ask what was the true first axiom of peano?, the book up there is the right one to search? and if peano really wrote "1 is element of Naturals" instead the "0" version, who corrected him?  or who was the person that historically is considered to put the 0 in the Naturals?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please start sentences and names with a capital, and end sentences with a full stop/period. Also the word *I* should be upper case. This is a forum, not a chat with your family.

Comment: There is no correction that needs to be made, and the distinction you're making is similar to saying that he didn't use the English word "natural". The use of $0$ as the "base case" probably (almost certainly, I suspect) came about as a way of incorporating as simple as possible Peano's axioms with the now standard [hierarchy of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe), which was slowly developed over a few decades early in the 20th century.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro since Peano use the Latin *numerus integer positivus* rather than *numerus naturalis*, there was no ambiguity even then

Comment: @Henry: My comment had more to do with the fact that the distinction, as far as the Peano axioms are concerned, the difference between $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ being a model for the Peano axioms and $\{1, 2, 3 \ldots \}$ being a model for the Peano axioms is analogous to the difference in writing "naturalis" and writing "natural". Note any countably infinite sequence of distinct objects is a model for the Peano axioms once an initial object is defined and the successor operation on the objects is defined. Whether or not we start with $0$ or with $1$ is a convention that is not relevant here.

Comment: What the OP should be asking, if anything, is when and why did the convention to begin with $0$ arise, and my earlier comment gives my thoughts on this. I doubt there is a reasonable way of assigning a suitable "first appearance" of starting with $0,$ and probably multiple instances of this can be found (perhaps even with Peano, who might have simply given $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ as an example satisfying his axioms), some of which could even by typos in the literature or certain textbook authors' quirks that had no effect on others at the time (late 1890s to 1920s).